# how to combine the tooltip together in a responsive highcharts

Tags: javascript, html, css, highcharts

[Here is the image of what i actually want as a final output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nv81T.png)

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/responsive/
The above is the link for the Highcharts and i want to **combine** the values of the tooltip of the date and the value of the stock together in a single tooltip. How should i do it?

```
highcharts
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be to set `split` property of tooltip with a false value and change series name to 'AAPL'.

API Reference:
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.split

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/896xsskw/

Answer (score 1):

check [tooltip.formatter](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.formatter) an format it accordingly

```
tooltip: {
  useHTML: true,
  formatter: function() {
    return '<small>' +
      Highcharts.dateFormat('%A,%b %d,%Y',
        new Date(this.x)) + '</small><br> '+
                "<span style='color:" + this.points[0].series.color +
                "'>\u25CF</span> " + this.points[0].series.name + ': <b> ' + this.y + '</b>';
  }
},
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kxLk5t0g/) demo

Comment: you can accept this answer as described [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)